# Получить json от php

Tags: jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток! подскажите,как правильно получить  ответ от php в переменные jquery? Имеется php скрипт который отдаёт строку json вида

```
'{"coord1":'.$row1['lat'].',"coord2":'.$row1['lng'].'} ';
```

хочу присвоить переменным значения coord1 и coord2, обращаюсь к файлу через ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.coord1);
        alert(data.coord2);
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо,немного поправил строку возврата и все заработало!

Answer (score 1):

php:

```
<?php    
    $result = array("coord1" => $row1['lat'], "coord2" => $row1['lng']);
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
 ?>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("/php/main.php", function(result){
      yourVariable = result.coord1;
    }, "JSON");
})
```

// Нужно подключить jQuery

Comment: Спасибо, но данные вариант неприемлем, я сначала посылаю  пост запрос идентификатором, данные по которому мне нужно вернуть.

Comment: Добавьте больше кода пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь функцией javascript - `JSON.parse();`

Подробнее здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/json